# How do I run a specific NPM command before build in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, npm, single-page-application

I am trying to run a specific NPM command for Angular within my ASP.NET Core application. The NPM is nothing special, it just prepares some files.

**How can I automate to run the NPM script before each build in ASP.NET Core?**

The Angular app is within the ClientApp folder, with the package.json in it.

Comment: If you used the default angular SPA Template it should come with Tasks setup that get executed when you run it (i.e. before build)

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#hook-scripts

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio (not Code) or something else? If so, you should probably look at pre-build events.

Comment: @A.Chiesa Yes, I use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just add a `Target` to your `.csproj` file that executes a script at certain steps. For example, the following will run the installed `gulp.cmd` just before the server application is built:

```
<Target Name="RunGulp" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you used the default angular SPA Template it should come with Tasks setup that get executed when you run it (i.e. before build).

From the default angular SPA template:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
        <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
```